# Unexpected token error in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to learn reactjs but I am bumping my head into an error and I cant understand how to get around it.

here is the code :

```
import React , {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import './footer.scss';


function NumberList(props){
    const numbers = props.numbers;
    const listItems = numbers.map((numbers) =>
        <li>{numbers}</li>
    );

    return(
        <ul>{listItems}</ul>
    );
}


const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
ReactDOM.render(
    <NumberList numbers={numbers}/>
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

and console is returning this :

```
/src/App.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected , (21:4)

  19 | ReactDOM.render(
  20 |     <NumberList numbers={numbers}/>
> 21 |     document.getElementById('root')
     |     ^
  22 | );
  23 | 
  24 |
```

I would like some help to fix this problem. Im new to reactjs so please be nice.

Thanks

EDIT ;

After fixing this error , my browser is returning this :

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
▶ 14 stack frames were collapsed.
(anonymous function)
src/index.js:7

   4 | import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
   5 | import './index.css';
   6 | 
>  7 | ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
   8 | registerServiceWorker();
   9 | 
  10 | 

View compiled
▶ 6 stack frames were collapsed.
This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.
```

Comment: typo use `,` to separate the arguments like this: `ReactDOM.render(
    <NumberList numbers={numbers}/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);`

Comment: can you show `App` component, App and NumberList two different component ?

Comment: @MayankShukla just fixed it thanks

Answer (score 0):

> typo use **,** to separate the arguments like this:

```
ReactDOM.render( <NumberList numbers={numbers}/>, document.getElementById('root') );
```

Comment: Thanks ! it fixed my error but browser is returning an error : see my edit

Answer (score -1):

Please convert "NumberList" to a react component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import './footer.scss';

class NumberList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const numbers = props.numbers;
        const listItems = numbers.map(numbers => <li>{numbers}</li>);

        return <ul>{listItems}</ul>;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't fix anything - your code is functionally identical to the [functional component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html) from the question.